# Strategy Pattern with Anonymous Function Closure

Tags: php, functional-programming, closures, anonymous-function, strategy-pattern

I want to implement the Stategy Pattern using Closures in php. The main advantage of using closure is to reduce the amount of boilerplate and code needed by creating additional classes. Usually the pattern looks like this:

```
interface StateDiscountCalculatorInterface
{
    public function calculateDiscount($amount);
}


class NewYorkStateStrategy implement StateDiscountCalculatorInterface
{
    public function calculateDiscount($amount)
    {
        // .... about 20 lines of code
    }
}

class CaliforniaStateStrategy implement StateTaxCalculatorInterface
{
    public function calculateDiscount($amount)
    {
       // .... about 20 lines of code that's different from New York State Strategy
    }
}

class stateTaxContext
{
    private $stategy;

    public function setStrategy(StateDiscountCalculatorInterface $strategy)
    {
        $this->strategy = $strategy;
    }

    public function getDiscount(array $amount)
    {
        return $this->strategy->calculateDiscount($amount);
    }

}
```

The version below is with a closure implementing a php functional interface. Is this the right way to do this?

```
interface StateDiscountCalculatorInterface
{
    public function calculateDiscount($amount);
}


class stateTaxContext
{
    private $newYorkStateStrategy;
    private $californiaStateStrategy;
    private $state;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->newYorkStateStrategy = function () implements StateDiscountCalculatorInterface {
            ...NewYorkStateStrategy class is replaced with code here
        };

        $this->californiaStateStrategy = function () implements StateDiscountCalculatorInterface {
            ...CaliforniaStateStrategy class is replaced with code here
        };
    }

    public function getDiscount(array $amount)
    {
        if($this->state==='california')
        {
            $this->californiaStateStrategy->calculateDiscount($amount);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I feel like this is a bad way to approach the problem. I don't know if there is anything more than a basic multiplier for tax, but I would create an array with the state name and the tax multiplier. For example array( 'Michigan' => 0.06, ' Nevada' => 0.0685, ...) and then just create a function to get the value using the state as the key and multiply it by the price

Comment: Otherwise you're creating 50+ classes or closures and that just doesn't seem like the best idea

Comment: This is oversimplification of the pattern, Imagine each class has amount 20 lines of operations to do. I'm not sure you're aware what the strategy pattern is judging by your answer.

Comment: I'd like to know as well, I'll wait for someone who knows more about closures than me to solve this. I still feel like this is the wrong reason to use closures. I think closures are used by $california = function($price) { return $price *0.0725 }, then you call it like if($state == 'California') { $tax = $california($price);}

Comment: I know you want to implement the strategy pattern, but I am not sure this is the best case for that. Maybe look at the Template Method

Comment: Think CR is a better match for this, but there isn't enough detail to judge the methods but none of them seems right to me. Are the taxes in the different states so different that you need the persions weight in one and how much the cusins earn in the other?

Comment: The code is just an example. I'm aware of the Template pattern and that's not what I need but thanks.

Comment: I edited the code so it's more obvious.

Comment: Use anonymous Class, a Closure can't implement an Interface if it's required by the client class contract. But an anonymous Class can. And you can inject into it other methods/dependencies too, even extend abstract or use Traits.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a design patterns expert, but to my mind one of the best approaches to implement a strategy pattern would be the following - you may keep the interface & strategy classes as they are, but implement context like this:

```
class StateTaxContext
{
    private $state;

    public function setState(StateDiscountCalculatorInterface $state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    public function getDiscount(array $amount)
    {
        return $this->state->->calculateDiscount($amount);
    }
}
```

And then you may use this pattern everywhere in your code like this:

```
$context = new StateTaxContext();

// Calculate NY discount?
$context->setState(new NewYorkStateStrategy());
$data = $context->getDiscount($amount);

// Calculate California discount?
$context->setState(new CaliforniaStateStrategy());
$data = $context->getDiscount($amount);
```

Comment: That's exactly the way I normally implement this pattern but I want to do it with a Closure as written in the original question.

Comment: Well, I get the idea, & I suppose it will work, but I don't think it is the best way to implement this pattern, at least because it is breaking SOLID principles  - good practice is that you want to keep each strategy's implementation logic in it's separate class (single-responsibility).

Comment: Are functions able to implement Interfaces? I doubt so. However you could try with an anonymous Class, like: `class implements Interface { { function... } }`.